# Removendo um elemento específico em um array

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array

```
$input = array("item 1", "item 2");
```

Mas como ele é dinâmico, os itens podem mudar

```
$input = array("item 2", "item 4");

$input = array("item 4");
```

É possível usar o `array_splice` para retirar, se existir, um elemento específico (item 2) do array?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Se souber a posição na array** pode usar o [unset();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) diretamente

```
unset($input[0]);
```

Para ser mais claro:

```
$input = array("item 2", "item 4");
var_dump($input);
unset($input[0]);
var_dump($input);
```

dá:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "item 2"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "item 4"
}
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "item 4"
}
```

**Se não souber a posição no array** tem de percorrer o array ou usar [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) primeiro e depois o `unset()`

```
$key = array_search('item 2', $input);
if($key!==false){
    unset($input[$key]);
}
```

Exemplo:

```
$input = array("item 2", "item 4");
$key = array_search('item 2', $input);
if($key!==false){
    unset($input[$key]);
}
var_dump($input);
```

que dá

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "item 4"
}
```

Comment: O seu exemplo usando o array_search funcionou para mim. Mas quando fui usar com o array gerado pelo WordPress (get_the_category( $post->ID ), ele continua imprimindo as duas categorias.

Comment: @marcelo2605 `get_the_category( $post->ID )` é a função que dá o valor que quer remover? ou é o $post que é a sua array?

Comment: é a função que gera o meu array: $input = get_the_category( $post->ID );

Comment: @marcelo2605 o que recebe quando faz `var_dump(get_the_category( $post->ID ))`?

Comment: encontrei a resposta aqui: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144617/38553
E acrescentei o seu if($key!==false){

Comment: @marcelo2605 essa resposta é basicamente o mesmo que a minha. Consegui pôr a funcionar?

Comment: Sim, consegui. Obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Você pode utilizar o "array_diff" para remover um ou mais elementos de uma array pelos valores:

```
$input = array("item 1", "item2", "item3", "item4");

$remover = array("item2");

$resultado = array_diff($input, $remover)
```

$resultado seria uma array apenas com "item 1", "item3", "item4".

Mas isso vale apenas se você quiser remover toda e qualquer ocorrência de um mesmo valor na sua array, ou seja, se houver dois elementos com "item2", ambos serão removidos.

Answer (score 1):

E caso o array onde se busca seja multidimensional, um complemento [à resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27447/250) do @Sergio, seria uma função originada nos comentários do manual do PHP (mas hoje, infelizmente perdida) que permite a busca recursivamente usando os próprios Iterators do PHP:

```
/**
 * Searches value inside a multidimensional array, returning its index
 *
 * Original function by "giulio provasi" (link below)
 *
 * @param mixed|array $haystack
 *   The haystack to search
 *
 * @param mixed $needle
 *   The needle we are looking for
 *
 * @param mixed|optional $index
 *   Allow to define a specific index where the data will be searched
 *
 * @return integer|string
 *   If given needle can be found in given haystack, its index will
 *   be returned. Otherwise, -1 will
 *
 * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#97645 (dead)
 */
function search( $haystack, $needle, $index = NULL ) {

    if( is_null( $haystack ) ) {
        return -1;
    }

    $arrayIterator = new \RecursiveArrayIterator( $haystack );

    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator( $arrayIterator );

    while( $iterator -> valid() ) {

        if( ( ( isset( $index ) and ( $iterator -> key() == $index ) ) or
            ( ! isset( $index ) ) ) and ( $iterator -> current() == $needle ) ) {

            return $arrayIterator -> key();
        }

        $iterator -> next();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Para usar basta informar o array onde buscar e aquilo que se procura. Caso a estrutura do array seja mais ou menos conhecida, você pode informar um terceiro argumento para que a busca fique restrita apenas aos sub-arrays com aquela chave.

Answer (score 0):

Bom estava buscando uma solução para algo semelhante e o que fiz pra resolver foi  varrer o array num foreach e retirar a variável encontrada com unset(); e criar um novo array ' $resultado' sem essa variável. Um exemplo a baixo.

```
$input = array 0 => ("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4")
         array 1 => ("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4")

$contador=0;

foreach ($input as $i):
        if(isset($i['item1'])): unset($i['item1']);  endif;
        $resultado[$contador++]=$i;
endforeach;

$resultado = array 0 => ( "item2", "item3", "item4")
             array 1 => ( "item2", "item3", "item4")
```

Obs. Sou novo aki e em programação tbm acredito que não seja a melhor solução mas resolveu no caso ;)

Answer (score -3):

Você pode utilizar assim:

```
let vet = ["Italo", "Joao", "Maria"];

let index = vet.indexOf("Italo")

if(index > -1) {
  vet.splice(index,1)
}
```

O `indexOf` vai procurar no teu vetor e retornará `0` se encontrar o valor, e `-1` se não encontrar. Atenção que é *case sensitive*.

Depois dentro do `if` o `splice` remove o elemento na posição passada.

Comment: A pergunta possui a tag de PHP, não JavaScript. Enquanto esta resposta pode funcionar em JavaScript, não é uma resposta válida pois não resolve o problema em PHP.

Answer (score -4):

Da pra usar o `array_diff($array_1, $array_2)`;

Onde o primeiro `$array_1`, é o array onde contém os seus dados, e o `$array_2` contém os dados que deseja excluir do primeiro

Ex:

```php
$input = ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', 'item_4'];
$new_input = array_diff($input, array('item_1', 'item_2'));
print_r($new_input);
```

Lembrando que ele não modifica os índices.
Resultado:

```
array(
   [2] => item_3
   [3] => item_4
)
```

Comment: Mas isso não é o mesmo que já foi respondido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27450/70)? Respostas adicionais são sempre bem-vindas (é recomendável, até), mas é importante que acrescentem algo de fato.