# Retirar apenas um valor na array

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma array desta forma

```
$arr = array('10', '12', '10', '15', '18', '18', '7', '18', '18', '15');
```

Quatro vezes o valor 18. Preciso retirar dela apenas um valor, exemplo um 18, e ela continuar assim:

```
$arr = array('10', '12', '10', '15', '18', '7', '18', '18', '15');
```

E isso com qualquer outro numero até zerar e não possuir mais nenhum numero, exemplo o 18, não tem limite de números.

Como se fosse uma logica de carrinho de compras

Tenho 10 produtos numero 18, se eu retirar um de cada vez, o numero 18 vai saindo da array

Espero que tenha ficado mais claro agora

Comment: Você quer tirar o último?

Comment: Como assim até zerar? Cada número só pode aparecer até 3 vezes? Não está clara a lógica.

Comment: Até zerar seria o array não ter mais elementos? Qual a lógica para determinar qual elemento deve sair? Aquele que se repetir mais? Por favor, [edit] a pergunta e seja claro na sua dúvida.

Comment: Pra zerar é facil, deleta o array :)   Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27445/removendo-um-elemento-espec%C3%ADfico-em-um-array

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de array_unique — Remove o valores duplicados de um array

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Ate zerar seria o caso, se tenho quatro números na array, vou retirando de um em um ate zerar, entendeu, como se fosse um carrinho de compras

Comment: @bfavaretto - Os números não tem limite, apenas preciso de retirar uma de cada vez se necessário, ou ate mesmo retirar todos porem tem que ser de um em um, ate zerar

Comment: Ok, retirar um a um enquanto houverem números. Isso ficou claro. Agora, como definir a ordem que devem ser retirados? Isso você ainda não explicou.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, retirar apenas um, independente da quantidade de vezes que ele repete, toda vez que eu chamar a função ele retiraria um numero que eu determinasse da array

Comment: @MarcosPaulo e como devem ficar os índices do array após a remoção do valor? Devem permanecer os mesmos ou reajustá-los?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não importa como retornam, basta apenas a remoção de cada um

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Removendo um elemento específico em um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27445/removendo-um-elemento-espec%c3%adfico-em-um-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso acha-se a posição com a função `array_search`:

```
$posicao = array_search('18',$arr);
```

E de seguida elimina-se essa posição com a função `unset`:

```
unset($arr[$posicao]);
```

Ou fazendo tudo junto:

```
unset($arr[array_search('18',$arr)]);
```

[Exemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2d7e8991cedc2f8c96bc481f481f0ede56b2c30)

Comment: Perfeito, deu certo aqui da forma que eu precisava